# Two questions regarding the fourth step of glycolysis

Tags: organic-chemistry, biochemistry, aldol-reaction

I am studying the 10 steps of glycolysis, and is currently on step 4. In this step, a molecule of fructose-1,6-biphosphate is cleaved into dihydroacetone phosphate (DHAP) and glyceraldehyde 3-phosphate (GAPD). I have two questions relating to the chemistry of this step:

1. Is this step considered a reverse aldol reaction? Since the products are a ketone (DHAP) and an aldehyde (GAPD), and the enzyme is called 'aldolase', I sense a strong hint that this is related to the aldol reaction.
2. If this is a reverse aldol reaction, why is the structure of fructose-1,6-biphosphate not similar to that of a typical aldol addition (or condensation) product?

I have tried to answer the these questions by attempting to work out the mechanism of the reverse direction of this step via aldol addition reaction, but was not able to come up with how a ring is formed after the addition product is made. Below is my picture:
[image]

I assume the conclusions to my questions could not be made because my mechanism is flawed. If so, which step had I gotten wrong? Would the role of the enzyme aldolase play a crucial role into answering my questions?

Thank you.